# LinQ group and sum two different type of lists and create Dictionary

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary, struct

)
i have a question about grouping and sum two list of different types. 
The situation:
i have a stock (we call it stockA) with a bucket, reference nr, pieces and more fields...
In stockB, we got just the reference nr and pieces

```
stockA
------
BucketNo [varchar(7)]
ReferenceNo [varchar(13)]
Productionpieces [int]

stockB
------
ReferenceNo [varchar(13)]
pieces [decimal(18,2)]
```

The data are coming with EF (that works fine !)

In my programm, i want to group and combine the reference nr, just into a dictionary (?).
At the runtime, i have to access a key very often. Get the pieces and subtract a value.
In my mind got a dictionary and at the runtime i want to access the key
dict[x].pieces -= 50;

The correct data coming with SQL with this statement:

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(ReferenceNo,' ','') as ReferenceNo,
    CONVERT(bigint,ISNULL(SUM(Pieces),0) + SNULL(SUM(Productionpieces ),0)) as Productionpieces 
from stockA 
    LEFT JOIN stockB on stockA.ReferenceNo = stockB.ReferenceNo 
where ReferenceNo <> NULL 
GROUP BY ReferenceNo
```

I have tried a couple of ways to get a KeyValuePair Object but at the runtime i got a same key exception, i guess i haven't joined the other tuple of data.
At the end of the story, i just want to combine two lists, sum and get keyvaluepairs!
Maybe you got a good example for me?

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking. You want to group all pieces by reference number and sum the value of the pieces? And what is this value you want to subtract? Also, why are your pieces in StockA and INT, and in StockB a Decimal?

Comment: Exactly! The reason for subtract is just a availability of products (reference number). At the runtime, i check each order and subtract the needed pieces from the grouped stock list. It's decimal, because the natural type of product requieres a decimal unit.

Comment: We need more information - show some EF classes, and some LINQ you currently are using to pull data. Or perhaps you can use my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) to convert your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to put in datatable and then use linq on table.  See code below :

```
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Your SQL Query", conn);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            Dictionary<string, long> dict = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("ReferenceNo"), y => y.Field<long>("Productionpieces"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: But in this case, i dont have to group the data again. Anyway, is there no groupby or groupjoin for the two lists/tables?

Comment: You need the use the GroupBy along with the ToDictionary.